# Kafka Streams: POJO serialization/deserialization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What class/method in Kafka Streams can we use to serialize/deserialize Java object to byte array OR vice versa?  The following link proposes the usage of  ByteArrayOutputStream & ObjectOutputStream but they are not thread safe.

[Send Custom Java Objects to Kafka Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141924/send-custom-java-objects-to-kafka-topic)

There is another option to use the ObjectMapper, ObjectReader (for threadsafe), but that's converting from POJO -> JSON -> bytearray.  Seems this option is an extensive one.  Wanted to check if there is a direct way to translate object into bytearray and vice versa which is threadsafe.  Please suggest

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
public class HouseSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T>{
    private Class<T> tClass;
    public HouseSerializer(){

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {
        tClass = (Class<T>) configs.get("POJOClass");       
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        //Object serialization to be performed here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: Kafka version - 0.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wanted to check if there is a direct way to translate object into bytearray

I would suggest you look at using [Avro serialization](https://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html) with the Confluent Schema Registry, if possible, but not required. JSON is a good fall back, but takes more space "on the wire", and so [MsgPack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) would be the alternative there.

[See Avro code example here](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer)

Above example is using the [avro-maven-plugin](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedjava.html) to generate a LogLine class from the `src/main/resources/avro` schema file.

---

Otherwise, it's up to you for [how to serialize your object into a byte array](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html), for example, a String is commonly packed as

```
[(length of string) (UTF8 encoded bytes)]
```

While booleans are a single 0 or 1 bit

> which is threadsafe

I understand the concern, but you aren't commonly sharing deserialized data between threads. You send/read/process a message for each independent one.

Comment: Thanks for the above response.  I understand that each message by itself would be a separate instance of Kafka object, but in order to cast it to a Java object and then serialize/deserialize we would potentially run into the racing conditions.  I was hoping if there is a way to convert the data value to a byte array within the above class method "serialize"

Comment: Avro/JSON does that for you and can be used across many different languages rather than just "default Java Object serialization". You don't need to go to a byte array yourself. Just use the StringSerializer if using JSON