# Json Parsing in Event Driven System

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I have a following use case :

- parse the json from stream (kafka topic)
- extract some fields (likely 35 out of 100 fields)
- Build a json out of those fields
- Publish it to pub/sub for further processing

My implementation is very much java language bound. Can anyone suggest optimal solution for this ? and why is it optimal ?

For json parsing, I am thinking of https://bolerio.github.io/mjson/

Comment: There's an example of building your own Json Serializer/Deserializer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524867/parsing-json-data-using-apache-kafka-streaming

Comment: Alternatively Spring Kafka will handle it for you, transparently mapping json to pojos and back https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: I don't want json to be bound to pojos. That's the reason I am asking for any sort of dynamic transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka includes **Jackson** JSON library and [includes its own JSON Deserializer](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.0/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonDeserializer.java) that returns a JsonNode class

Alternatively,as listed in the comments, you can use higher level frameworks such as Spring, Vertx, Quarkus, etc to build Kafka consumers

For the listed use case, I would opt for Spark, Flink, or NiFi for integration with PubSub. Each also offering JSON proessing, with NiFi being more advanced in that it can do [JSONPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonPathReader/index.html)